# Home brewed and item, and now

Tags: magic-items, homebrew

I have made a box that I have allowed my players to find, it is the Mystical Box of locks, Mark 4. They were given one key to the box, let's call this the red key. The Red key opens the red lock. pretty easy right? Inside they found the remaining three keys, for simplicity let's call these the Orange, Yellow, and Green key. the magic of this item is when the Orange key is used it opens up the orange compartment, while if both Red and orange keys are used it opens a third compartment. my problem comes from this:

if I start back at the beginning with one key and one lock, it opens one compartment, while 2 keys give me 3 compartments (red, orange, and red/orange), 3 keys give me 7 compartments (R, O, Y, R/O, R/Y, O/Y, R/O/Y) and the 4 keys give me 15. every new tier I get double + 1 of the previous. so logically 5 keys should yield 31 compartments, but when I mapped it out I only came up with 30. at 6 keys I should have 63 compartments but only can figure out 60 combinations. the mythical box that I have hinted at has 7 keys. if the pattern follows what it should it would be 127 compartments but I have 121 mapped. did I F up somewhere or is there some formula that I am missing?

help me Inter-web Kenobi, you're my only hope.

for anyone wondering the dimensions of the box are 24' x 18' x 12' or 3 cubic feet, (I'm an idiot. but I'm not stupid :))

Comment: You'd have to share the map you made if you want us to figure out what you're missing, but this sounds like a simple listing problem.

Comment: I am not sure this belongs on rpg.se. While the source of the Q is in an rpg, the problem itself is not related to them at all. Maths or puzzle SE might be more appropriate.

Comment: Possibly just out of interest, which RPG is this for? Not that I suspect it to have a meaningful impact on the answer. (I'll leave the on-topicness matter to others, but leave the thought that RPG questions often bleed over to other arts (ie. other stacks) but there can be real utility in asking RPGrs so you get a RPGer answer.)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about math, not roleplaying.

Comment: @Szega: Agreed, and I've just cast the fifth close vote. TBH, I'm a little bit on the fence here, since we *have* traditionally allowed some fairly pure math questions arising from RPG mechanics, and don't seem to have suffered for it. But I do feel there is a difference between asking a math question arising from something specific to RPGs (like "when is advantage in D&D 5e better than +2 to hit?") and asking about a generic combinatorical puzzle that the asker just happened to come up with while running a RPG.

Answer (score 5):

### Your intuition is right and you've probably messed up your list

Your intuition about the number pattern is correct. If you have a set of \$x\$ keys that can be combined in \$y\$ ways, adding another key to that set doubles the number of possible combinations because for each existing combination, you add a new combination which is just the original combination plus the new key - and then finally add one more "combination" which is the new key by itself. So, by induction, for the set of \$x + 1\$ keys, there must be \$2 \times y + 1\$ combinations, and we also know that for the case where \$x = 1\$, \$y = 1\$ - there's only one possible combination of one key.

The generic formula that would express this is that for \$n\$ keys, there are \$2^n - 1\$ combinations. This happens to be exactly how we count in a binary number system - the largest decimal number that can be expressed in a binary number of up to \$n\$ bits is \$2^n - 1\$. This suggests a convenient way you can map out your combinations - use a table of binary numbers! You can list all the non-zero binary numbers that fit in \$n\$ bits and then treat each 0/1 digit as the absence or presence of a particular key.

Here's an example for the set of just 4 keys:

\begin{array} {|cccc|l|}\hline \text{Red} & \text{Ora} & \text{Yel} & \text{Gre} & \text{Contents} \\ \hline 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \text{more keys} \\ \hline 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \text{a rock} \\ \hline 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 10\ \text{gp} \\ \hline 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \text{a chicken} \\ \hline 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \text{roast chicken} \\ \hline 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & \text{hand grenade} \\ \hline 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & \text{spaghetti stash} \\ \hline 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \text{a pint of beer} \\ \hline 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \text{a pint of whiskey} \\ \hline 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & \text{the meaning of life} \\ \hline 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & \text{your father's approval} \\ \hline 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \text{bag of holding} \\ \hline 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \text{bag of devouring} \\ \hline 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \text{Elminster's mix tape} \\ \hline 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \text{feline zombie} \\ \hline \end{array}

Hopefully the pattern of number progression is obvious, so you can see how you'd lay out a table of 7 keys - and by doing it this way you'll make it much harder to accidentally miss out any possible combinations.

Comment: The meaning of life should really have been in compartment 101010, but that would have required you mapping out for six keys which seems excessive.

Comment: @Someone_Evil strictly, my numbers here must be little-endian for the ascending pattern to make sense, so that should be compartment 010101... (thanks for the formatting improvements, btw.)

Comment: I take it the feline zombie is a bobcat?